# How to link between two xcode applications

Tags: xcode, swift

I have two pieces of code in seperate projects, one code to convert img to text and display it in a box, and another seperate app that converts inputted text to speach.

I would like to know how to take the converted text from the first app and make the second read it out loud.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you...

> App Groups allow access to group containers that are shared among multiple related apps, and allows certain additional interprocess communication between apps.
>   [Sharing Data with Your Containing App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)